# Run macOS as guest VM OS within VMware Fusion

Tags: vmware

Is it possible to install macOS as the guest OS within a VM in [VMware Fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Fusion)?

I am running macOS Mojave on a Mac mini (2018). I want to run virtual machines inside of which is running macOS Mojave or Catalina. I am *not* trying to run Microsoft Windows, not at all.

[Parallels is unusable with macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/364456/17907) as the guest OS. So I need an alternative.

Comment: `VirtualBox` seems to be able to run many versions of MacOS. I am using it for many Unixes and it looks like a very professionnal software (0 crash / 2 years ~= 1 full month of use).

Comment: You should not get excited by one report of a problem.  Nearly a 100% of software has  bugs.  Lot of bugs result from some unique set of circumstances that you hope not to encounter. I'm running High Sierra in Parallels.  With Parallels you would need to purchase an upgrade to run Catalina.  You need to purchase an upgrade for every new macOS.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos I have not been so fortunate running macOS in virtual box. I managed to get one point release of macOS to run in one point release of virtualbox.  A change in versions of macOS or VirtualBox resulted in failure.  virtualbox runs Linux distros just fine. I have not tried running macOS in Virtual Box in two years.

Comment: Have you tried the free version of Parallels in the AppStore?  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/parallels-desktop-lite/id1085114709?mt=12 Hurry, I've heard the free version will not be free much longer.

Comment: @nohillside  What unclear about this? Poster heard rumors that there are problems running macOS in Virtual Machines.  Wants other user to chime in that they have successfully run macOS Mojave or Catalina in a virtual machine.

Comment: @historystamp please read the on-hold notice. The question asks whether VMware can run macOS as a guest. This is easily answerable by just visiting the VMware website so the question lacks any research.

Comment: Also keep in mind that questions asking for experiences with various scenarios usually get put in hold for being primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @nohillside Actually the Question is *not* easily answerable with a visit to the product web site. It took much digging to find one bare mention in a list. Their web site is all about running Windows on your Mac, not macOS.

Comment: It's right on https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html, *and* on the Wiki page you referenced in the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

According to [this product brochure page](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html) comparing the *Fusion* and *Fusion Pro* feature sets, there is an item listed that is checked for both editions:

> Support for macOS Mojave Host and Guest

I currently run Mojave as a guest OS in VMware Fusion version 11.1 on a Mac mini (2018) with 32 gigs of RAM running macOS Mojave 10.14.5 as the host OS.

[image: screenshot of macOS Mojave running as a guest OS within a VM by VMware Fusion]

Fusion offered to create a guest OS using the Recovery volume of the host Mojave. Unfortunately, when I chose that option it then reported an error saying I have no Recovery volume. (I doubt that, as Parallels did successfully make a macOS VM from my Recovery volume.) Anyways, I had *Install macOS Mojave.app* downloaded in my Applications folder. I dragged that into the Fusion "new" VM dialog box, and it worked to install macOS in the new VM.

On the upside, I have not seen the disappearing mouse pointer as was seen in Parallels as [linked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/364456/17907) in the Question. On the downside, I have not yet been able to resize the virtual display in Fusion despite installing *VMware Tools* utility within the guest OS; the screen is stuck at 1024 x 768 resolution within the macOS guest OS. These virtualizers *never* run perfectly smoothly, it seems, there are always problems and limitations.

Tip: As a Parallels customer, you [qualify for a discount](https://store.vmware.com/store?Action=html&Env=BASE&Locale=en_US&SiteID=vmware&pbPage=fusion-vs-parallels&src=WWW_eBIZ_productpage_Fusion_Parallels_US) if you decide to go with Fusion.